# How to replicate the Scale Up Animation when an app starts regularly (push app icon on HomeScreen) on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation, cgaffinetransform

i want to replicate the animation when an app starts on iPhone.
There is the first view scaling up from 50 % to 100% i think.
later I want to use this as a transition between 2 views.
Any ideas how to replicate, or is there a ready to use solution from apple in the sdk?
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the same thing with CABasicAnimation and CAAnimationGroup, I actually thought that Core Animation over UIKit Animations was smoother and It gives you more control.

```
CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = YES;

CABasicAnimation *fadeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.00];

animationGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fadeAnimation, scaleAnimation, nil];

[self.layer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"fadeAnimation"];
self.layer.opacity = 1.0;
```

"There's always more then one way to skin a cat"

Comment: Apparently removedOnCompletion is ignored by CAAnimationGroup: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CAAnimationGroup_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @NaXir try to set the ".fillMode" property of the animation.  Also, make sure that if you are animating the same "animationWithKeyPath" you might need to introduce a delay relative to the media time.

Answer (score 6):

You can apply a scale transform to the UIView and then animate it back to it's normal state.

```
// Set the the view's scale to half
[viewToScale setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5,0.5)];

// Set the transform back to normal (identity) in an animation when you're
// ready to animate
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[viewToScale setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The trick will be you will need to set the view to the smaller scale in a separate run cycle from the animation or you won't see the view animate. So you can set the smaller scale and then call *-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:* to actually perform the animation.

Comment: thank you very much :)
i defined viewToScale.alpha = 0.5; before animation to animate it to alpha 1.0, i thought this was missing in my plan :) but now it looks great!