# CABasicAnimation to make NSView flip

Tags: objective-c, calayer, nsview, cabasicanimation, caanimation

I'm making a card game for mac and I'm using a CABasicAnimation to making the card flip around. It's almost working, but it could be a bit better.

As it works now, the card flips inwards (to the left) - Screenshot 1. When the card has moved "flipped" all the way to the left, I change the image of the NSView and flip the card outwards again - Screenshot 2.

**Screenshot 1 (flipping in):**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Screenshot 2 (flipping out):**

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Code for flipping in:**

```
- (void)flipAnimationInwards{
    // Animate shadow
    NSShadow *dropShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [dropShadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0, 1)];
    [dropShadow setShadowBlurRadius:15];
    [dropShadow setShadowColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5]];
    [[self animator] setShadow:dropShadow];

    // Create CAAnimation
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI/2];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 3.1;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0; 
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [rotationAnimation setValue:@"flipAnimationInwards" forKey:@"flip"];
    rotationAnimation.delegate = self;

    // Get the layer
    CALayer* lr = [self layer];

    // Add perspective
    CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
    mt.m34 = 1.0/-1000;
    lr.transform = mt;

    // Set z position so the layer will be on top
    lr.zPosition = 999;

    // Keep cards tilted when flipping
    if(self.tiltCard)
        self.frameCenterRotation = self.frameCenterRotation;

    // Do rotation
    [lr addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"flip"];
}
```

**The code for flipping out:**

```
- (void)flipAnimationOutwards{
    // Set correct image
    if (self.faceUp){
        [self setImage:self.faceImage];
    }else{
        [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Card_Background"]];
    }

    // Animate shadow
    NSShadow *dropShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [dropShadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0, 1)];
    [dropShadow setShadowBlurRadius:0];
    [dropShadow setShadowColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0]];
    [[self animator] setShadow:dropShadow];

    // Create CAAnimation
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI/2];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 3.1;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0; 
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    [rotationAnimation setValue:@"flipAnimationOutwards" forKey:@"flip"];
    rotationAnimation.delegate = self;

    // Get the layer
    CALayer* lr = [self layer];

    // Add perspective
    CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
    mt.m34 = 1.0/1000;
    lr.transform = mt;

    // Set z position so the layer will be on top
    lr.zPosition = 999;

    // Keep cards tilted when flipping
    if(self.tiltCard)
        self.frameCenterRotation = self.frameCenterRotation;

    // Commit animation
    [lr addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"flip"];
}
```

**The problem:**

The flipping out part looks fine. The right side of the card is taller/stretched than the left side, like it's supposed to be.

Flipping in is not perfect though. Here the right side is smaller/stretched, when it should be the left side that is taller/stretched.

**How do I make the left side taller/stretched on flipping in, instead of making the right side smaller/stretched?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask:

> How do I make the left side taller/stretched on flipping in, instead of making the right side smaller/stretched?

You also say that flipping out works fine but flipping in is wrong.

The difference between the two is in the sign of the perspective:

#### Flipping out code:

```
CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
mt.m34 = 1.0/1000; // note the lack of a minus sign
lr.transform = mt;
```

#### Flipping in code:

```
CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
mt.m34 = 1.0/-1000; // note the minus sign
lr.transform = mt;
```

If you want the two to look the same then they should most likely have the same perspective.

---

In my experience you usually want the negative perspective value (as you have done in the flipping in example). This has to do with the fact that the value represents the position of the "eye" / "camera" / "observer" or whatever you call it.

If you imagine a 3D scene where the position of the eye is (e<sub>x</sub>, e<sub>y</sub>, e<sub>z</sub>) then the perspective part of the transform is:

[image: perspective transform]

Assuming that you are looking at right at the world (i.e. not looking at it from the side) the position would be (0, 0, e<sub>z</sub>) which is the reason why we usually only set `m34` (3rd column, 4th row) when adding perspective to a transform.

You can also see that this is how it is used in the Core Animation Programming Guide:

> **Listing 5-8** Adding a perspective transform to a parent layer
>
> ```
> CATransform3D perspective = CATransform3DIdentity;
> perspective.m34 = -1.0/eyePosition;
> ```

If the rotation looks wrong to you should probably rotate in the other direction (for example changing a rotation from 0 to π into a rotation from 0 to -π or the other way around: changing a rotation from π to 0 into a rotation from -π to 0.

Comment: Hi David. I haven't had time to test out the code yet, but the bounty is about to expire. From what I can see, this would work. Thanks for the answer and keep up the good work.

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk Let me know when you have tried and I can see if I can clarify something

Answer (score 0):

What about adding some scale while you flip the card?

You could even exaggerate it and it would look as if someone lifted the card in order to flip it.

---

Some code to scale a view inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463362/1049134):

```
CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.3];
```

Comment: That sounds like an interesting idea. Can you give an example on how you'd do that?

Comment: Added some code although I don't do as much OS X as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, this is late answer, but I wrote easy usage solution.

### FlipTransition

```swift
import Cocoa

public final class FlipTransition: NSObject {
    
    private var srcView, dstView: NSView?
    
    private var duration: TimeInterval = 0.3
    
    public func flip(
        from srcView: NSView,
        to dstView: NSView,
        duration: TimeInterval = 0.3
    ) {
        
        self.duration = duration
        self.srcView = srcView
        self.dstView = dstView
        
        srcView.isHidden = false
        dstView.isHidden = true
        
        // Get super layer
        
        guard let superLayer = srcView.superview?.layer else {
            return
        }
        
        // Setup super layer 3d perspective
        
        var transform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform3D.m34 = -1 / 1000
        
        let translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(
            superLayer.bounds.midX,
            superLayer.bounds.midY,
            .zero
        )
    
        superLayer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DConcat(
            transform3D,
            translation
        )
        
        // Set layer anchor & position to center
        
        [srcView, dstView]
            .compactMap(\.layer)
            .forEach { layer in
                layer.anchorPoint = .init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            }
        
        // Start src view animation
        
        animate(
            srcView,
            from: CATransform3DIdentity,
            to: CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi / -2, 0, 1, 0)
        ) { f in
            self.startSecondStep()
        }
    }
    
    private func startSecondStep() {
        
        guard let srcView = srcView, let dstView = dstView else {
            return
        }
        
        srcView.isHidden = true
        dstView.isHidden = false
        
        animate(
            dstView,
            from: CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 1, 0),
            to: CATransform3DIdentity
        ) { f in
            self.finish()
        }
    }
    
    private func finish() {
        
        guard let srcView = srcView, let dstView = dstView else {
            return
        }
        
        srcView.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
        dstView.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
        
        [srcView, dstView]
            .compactMap(\.layer)
            .forEach { layer in
                layer.anchorPoint = .zero
            }
        
        srcView.superview?.layer?.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
    }
    
    // MARK: - Animation Utility
    
    private class AnimationDelegate: NSObject, CAAnimationDelegate {
        
        private let completion: (Bool) -> Void
        
        init(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
            self.completion = completion
        }
        
        func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) { }
        
        func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
            completion(flag)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func animate(
        _ view: NSView,
        from: CATransform3D,
        to: CATransform3D,
        completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void
    ) {
        
        let dstRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
        dstRotation.fromValue = from
        dstRotation.toValue = to
        dstRotation.duration = duration / 2
        dstRotation.fillMode = .forwards
        dstRotation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        dstRotation.delegate = AnimationDelegate(completion: completion)
        
        view.layer?.add(dstRotation, forKey: "flip")
    }
    
}
```

### Usage

```swift
FlipTransition().flip(from: srcView, to: dstView)
```

### View Structure

```
holderView {
    srcView,
    dstView
}
```

`dstView` initially should be hidden (`dstView.isHidden = true`). `holderView`, `srcView` and `dstView` should have equal sizes.